# C# TextBox Change Event in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView with several columns of TextBoxes.  I need to capture the event where they are done entering data, and are exiting the box (via Tab, Enter, Mouse click elsewhere, etc)

I have searched SO and Google, and it seems like you have to build an event from scratch.  I've tried multiple variations on what I have found since I can't seems to find one that fits with my particular needs.
I've been at this for longer than I care to admit and I need help.

Here is what I have...

```
    // Select DataGridView EditingControlShowing Event
    Private void gridData_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
        e.Control.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        Control cntObject = e.Control;
        cntObject.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
    }

    // TextBox TextChanged Event
    Private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Checks to see if the AddlQty field was altered
        if (gridData.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "AddlQty") {
            // Validate Entry
            if (e.Text is Not numeric) {
                MessageBox.Show("Entry Not Valid, Only Numeric Values Accepted");
            } else {
                CalcFinalQty(e.RowIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

For the record, the code does NOT work, the validation is quasi code and I'm getting an error in the function heading.  The important part for me is the

```
if (gridData.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "AddlQty"){ }
```

I just need help getting to that point.

Comment: A DataGridView column is quite different from a TextBox so trying to use text control events on columns wont work....if that is what you are trying to do.  The event args are completely different as your code shows: `DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs ` is not the same as `EventArgs`

Comment: Are you asking for when they leave the entire DataGridView or when they leave a specific cell? Maybe you coul duse a CurrentCellChanged in the dgv events. Or  if it's an actual TextBox you are using, look for those specific keys themselves (Tab, Enter, Mouse click away)

Comment: Do you mean the [DataGridView.CellEndEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit) event? Or [DataGridView.CellValidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating) event?

Comment: @Jimi  YES, that's exactly what I needed, thank you!